# iterate through a list of data frames and mutate columns

Tags: r

with data frames like below, I want to use a for loop to iterate through each data frame and add some new column say `new` & `new1` to the data frames `d1` and `d2`. Below is what I have tried.

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)

for(df in my.list) {
  df$new <- df$y1 + df$y2
  df$new1 <- df$y1 - df$y2
}
```

However when I look at the original data frames `d1` and `d2` they do not show the new col `new`.

```
> colnames(d1)
[1] "y1" "y2"
> colnames(d2)
[1] "y1" "y2"
```

How do I got about getting new columns added to the original data frames `d1` and `d2` ?

Comment: `lapply(my.list,function(x)transform(x,new=y1+y2))`

Comment: @Onyambu - updated the question to have more than one column transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an option with `lapply`

```
lst <- lapply(my.list, transform, new = y1 + y2, new1 = y1 - y2)
```

It is better to keep the 'data.frame's in the `list` and not to update the objects on the global environment.  But, if it is really needed

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
d1
#  y1 y2 new new1
#1  1  4   5   -3
#2  2  5   7   -3
#3  3  6   9   -3
```

#### data

```
my.list <- mget(paste0("d", 1:2))
```

Comment: it didn't give the expected results `> d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
> d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
> my.list <- list(d1, d2)
> lapply(my.list, transform, new = y1 + y2, new1 = y1 - y2)
[[1]]

[[2]]

> colnames(d1)
[1] "y1" "y2"
> colnames(d2)
[1] "y1" "y2"
> `  was expecting columns `new` and `new1`.

Comment: @user3206440  Do you meant to update the original dataset objects?  It is better to place datasets in the list rather than updating the original dataset

Comment: @user3206440   Updated the post

Comment: getting error `> list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
Error in list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x`

Comment: @user3206440  If you notice my `list`.  I created a named list.  i.e. `mget(paste0("d", 1:2))`.  In your case, `my.list <- list(d1 = d1, d2 = d2)`

Comment: why would you say that `It is better to place datasets in the list rather than updating the original dataset` ?

Comment: @user3206440  Reason is that most of the functions can be applied to all the datasets in a list  with `lapply/sapply`etc.  Suppose, you are updating each time the objects in the global environment, it is still an additional step without much benefit.  In the end, you may want to write those output, which is also easier within in the list

Answer (score 3):

The map-version looks as follows:

```
library(purrr) # part of the tidyverse
map(my.list, ~ mutate(.x, new = y1 + y2))
```

`~` creates and anonymous function.

Comment: For reproducible code, you could include `library(wherever_map_comes_from)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use lapply or Map/map, rather than for.

```
lapply(my.list, function(df) {df$new <- df$y1 + df$y2; df})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

`for(df in 1:length(my.list)) {
  my.list[[df]]$new <- my.list[[df]]$y1 + my.list[[df]]$y2
}`